# Laravel 6 validation: there is limit in number of rules?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-validation

I am using Laravel 6.13.1.

I have the following validation

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|max:100',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'mobile_number' => 'required',
    'date_of_birth' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    'category' => 'required',
    'other_category' => 'required_if:category,==,Others',
    'sub_caste' => 'required',
    'photo' => 'required',
    'status' => 'required|integer',
    'father_name' => 'required',
    'father_occupation' => 'required',
]);


if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();                    
}
```

It has 12 rules and it works. If I add one more rule then the validator stops working.

{{$errors}} gives an empty array in the view file.

Edit 1: The validation with 12 rules shows all error messages, but if I add one more validation like

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|max:100',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'mobile_number' => 'required',
    'date_of_birth' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    'category' => 'required',
    'other_category' => 'required_if:category,==,Others',
    'sub_caste' => 'required',
    'photo' => 'required',
    'status' => 'required|integer',
    'father_name' => 'required',
    'father_occupation' => 'required',
    'mother_name' => 'required',         
]);
```

then no error messages. {{$errors}} is an empty array.

In my view, I am using the following code to list errors

> ```
>       @if (count($errors) > 0)
>       <div class="alert alert-danger">
>         <ul>
>           @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
>           <li>{{ $error }}</li>
>           @endforeach
>         </ul>
>       </div>
>       @endif
> ```

Edit 2: I tried the same validation on Laravel 5.5 and it works well as indented.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a limit. How does it stop working? Can you show the validator with 13 rules?

Comment: could you add the last `rule` that stops your validation ?

Comment: @anber stops working means, no error messages.

Comment: @joseph I added the last rule.

Comment: could you try to stop the `redirect` method and try to return only with error like this
`return  $validator->errors();` to see what happens here

Comment: @Joseph I tried return $validator->errors(); Its showing the errors

Comment: that's good so your problem here in the blade i think or you could just use the normal validate method not the `Validator` facades

Comment: @Joseph I updated the question with blade error listing, I already tried validation without Facade.

Comment: really that is weird,let me search for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206992/discussion-between-joseph-and-joyal).

Comment: Instead of using $ Validator, you could use Request. The Request rules would look like the validation rules like: 'required', 'unique' and so on.
It would be simpler for you to work with them !!

Comment: Did you try to use @if($erros->any()) blade directive ?

Comment: I tried, the same issue. :(

Comment: @leonardo Yes I tried.

Comment: can you try $request->validate([...rules...]);

Comment: I already tried that, same result

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your form. I tried and everything works fine.

Comment: I faced a similar issue too. What I have experienced was, when form inputs increase to a certain number. Validation not working anymore. $errors array totally empty. But when inputs and validation rules decreased, it works perfectly. I did a similar scenario in Laravel 5.5 & 5.8. It works. While 6.0 it doesnt works anymore. Hope anyone could help over this as I have been looking around for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it has a limit, However you can create a request and put all your validation on it like that:

```
php artisan make:request UserRequest
```

You can check out this link [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#creating-form-requests)

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem, and found somewhere that maybe this is caused by the size of error messages. I've changed the SESSION_DRIVER env option from "cookie" to "file" and it worked!